# Use argument for find

Tags: shell

I want use argument in shell script between * *

It doesn't work.

How can I make it ??

search.sh

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                          
echo $1

find /data/ -iname '*${1}*'
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552144/find-using-regex-with-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552144/find-using-regex-with-variables) - already asnwered here. Please check this link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single-quotes block $-expressions from being evaluated/expanded. You need to use double-quotes instead.